# Using Squid and Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, squid

I've installed squid3 on my Ubuntu 12.04. I changed the http_port to 80. When I type 10.1.1.103 in the "The requested URL could not be retrieved" from squid. Do I have to run Apache as my web server or squid has a web server itself to run the web files? I am a little bit confused here. I am asked to setup squid on top of apache but I can't find the way to integrate them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to achieve this with one machine then you would normally setup squid to listen on port 80 and apache on port 8080 (or something else). Squid receives a request on port 80, then forwards it to apache on port 8080 (if it can't read from cache).

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have found this http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/install_squid_apache_on_1_server/ which is exactly what you are saying but I couldn't make it work.